# Define an anonymous struct in function call

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters, anonymous-struct

I can already do this:

```
struct {
    uint64 _i;
    bool operator()(uint64 elem)
    {
        const uint64 i = _i++; return elem & i; // Just an example
    }
} filter;

// Templated function
Array<uint64> clone = Containers::filter(array, filter);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to move the struct definition right inside the function call, so that I could for example define a macro like this one:

```
Array<uint64> clone = Containers::filter(array, ENUMERATE(i, elem, elem & i)); // Same as above
```

When I try this I get `expected primary-expression before 'struct'`:

```
Array<uint64> clone = Containers::filter(array, struct {
    uint64 _i;
    bool operator()(uint64 elem)
    {
        const uint64 i = _i++; return elem & i;
    }
});
```

Comment: You're looking for *lambdas*.

Comment: @Quentin I cannot have members like the counter `_i` in lambdas, can I? That's the reason why I used a struct in this case

Comment: Yes you can, lambda captures become members of the lambda object. And since C++14 you can add arbitrary captures as well.

Comment: Lambdas almost work, but I still have to define the counter `i` before, right? I tried `[&, i = 0](uint64 elem) -> bool { return elem & i++; }` but `i` is read-only

Comment: Yep, lambdas are `const` by default. Just add `mutable` before `-> bool` to make it mutable :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Write it as an answer if you want

Comment: I think your example has UB, better initialize `_i`, just to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements can be satisfied with a stateful, mutable lambda:

```
Array<uint64> clone = Containers::filter(
    array,
    [_i = uint64{0}](uint64 elem) mutable -> bool {
        const uint64 i = _i++;
        return elem & i;
    }
);
```